# Devise not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed devise and put

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'bluemage.systems'}
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false
config.action_mailer.default charset: 'utf-8'

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :address => "localhost",
  :port    => 25,
  :domain  => 'bluemage.systems'
  tls: false,
  enable_starttls_auto: false,
}
```

in the /config/environments/production.rb Like the instructions said on the github page,, but I look in my email and there is nothing. Is there something else that I need to do?

Comment: Set `raise_delivery_errors` to _true_ if you actually want to make sure things are working. Otherwise any errors will just get swallowed.

Comment: change `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` so you can check the console for errors.

Answer (score 0):

This should be the server host name of you web app:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {:host => 'www.servername.com'}
```

and this should be you mail server domain:

```
:domain  => 'mail.bluemage.com'
```

Comment: ok, looks like i need a mail server, is there a drag and drop solution?